# Rails Creating a Variable with text and a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to do this:

```
headline = 'Created a new' && link_to('Set', set_path(set))
```

Also tried:

```
headline = 'Created a new' + link_to('Set', set_path(set))
```

but it does't output like:

```
Created a new <a href="xxxx">Set</a>
```

Ideas? thxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just put this straight into your view, or in a helper. You can also simplify your `link_to` somewhat:

```
<%= 'Created a new' + link_to('Set', set) %>
# or 
<%= "Created a new #{link_to('Set', set)}" %>
# or 
Created a new <%= link_to('Set', set) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails has a nifty XSS prevention feature that might be getting in your way here. Before outputting strings, it will encode any HTML found in them by default, unless they were explicitly marked as safe strings ahead of time. `link_to` runs `html_safe!` on its output, which is why it isn't usually encoded, but adding it to an unsafe string like `'Created a new'` removes that HTML-safe attribute.

Try calling:

```
headline.html_safe!
```

immediately after setting it.

Of course, since the question doesn't specify what output you get instead of what you want, I can't be totally sure that this is the issue. But it's the best I can do with what I've got :)

Comment: Thanks, how should I create the headline var? I show'd a few ideas up top, not sure which if any are right.

Comment: Appending the string with `+` is correct. `&&` is used for boolean expressions, e.g. `obj.something_is_true? && obj.somthing_else_is_true?`, whereas `+` will concatenate two strings :)